# how to make home activity visible after login activity kill and home button pressed

Tags: android, android-homebutton

After successful login the Login activity launched the second activity.
I want my first activity(Login activity) not to be shown after successful login, for that i called finish() method after login But after the home button pressed, instead of home button again the login activity recreated.?But i expected the home activity to be shown when task again started from recent app list, instead of the login activity.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the reference of two exact questions 
[App always starts fresh from root activity instead of resuming background state (Known Bug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280361/app-always-starts-fresh-from-root-activity-instead-of-resuming-background-state) and [How to return to the latest launched activity when re-launching application after pressing HOME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337217/how-to-return-to-the-latest-launched-activity-when-re-launching-application-afte)

Here is what one of the answers have mentioned:

> This is due to the intents being used to start the app being different. Eclipse starts an app using an intent with no action and no category. The Launcher starts an app using an intent with android.intent.action.MAIN action and android.intent.category.LAUNCHER category. The installer starts an app with the android.intent.action.MAIN action and no category.

Hope it helps. For more you may read the other two questions.